# Force identifier case sensitivity in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, when one uses non-quoted identifiers, they are silently capitalized. In other words these two statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT name FROM my_table
SELECT "NAME" FROM "MY_TABLE"
```

Is there any way to stop the silent capitalization, so that the following statements become equivalent?

```
SELECT name FROM my_table
SELECT "name" FROM "my_table"
```

Comment: If you create the tables with table names in qoutes it should work as you like it.

Comment: I believe the quoted identifers are the way to stop the behaviour, not aware of a global setting to change it.

Comment: @eisberg, the table is already created with lower case characters.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov, please read again the question.

Comment: @linepogl Reading your question again. And if your goal is to change the silent behavior of Oracle and stop it from silently capitalizing the answer is just *no*.

Comment: @eisberg, yes, this is exactly my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't customize [how Oracle interprets your identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#i27570):

> Note that Oracle interprets the following names the same, so they cannot be used for different objects in the same namespace:
>
> ```
> employees
> EMPLOYEES
> "EMPLOYEES"
> ```

It is a convenience (backward compatibility?) that non-quoted identifiers are converted to upper-case (internally all object names are case-sensitive).